# Font showing in font display panel but does not render correctly in Power Point

Tags: fonts, rendering

I've recently installed a font on a second PC (works perfectly on my other PC) but while I can see it in the fonts panel and select it - it renders as some kind of old typewriter font. Any idea why?

Font installed: Korolev

Comment: What OS is this?